# Two bodies collision phaser

Tags: phaser-framework

I built a treasure hunt game with Phaser framework. I have my player and the treasure. But when the player collides with the treasure, the game is not stopping like it's supposed to.

I tried multiple syntax from different websites. The `game.physics.arcade.overlap()` seems to be the right function with the right syntax.

This is the error I'm getting for the collisionHandler: [physicsType error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YM5I.png)

I want the game to stop with a win message and exit the game.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>TreasureHunter</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <script src="js/phaser.min.js"> </script>

</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var game = new Phaser.Game(640,640,Phaser.AUTO,'',{preload: preload, create: create , update: update});

    var player;
    var cursors;
    var go = false;
    var static;


    function preload()
    {
        game.load.image('background', 'assets/background.png');
        game.load.spritesheet('dude', 'assets/dude.png',32,48);
        game.load.image('treasure', 'assets/treasure.png');
    }

    function create()
    {
        // game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
        game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.P2JS);

        game.add.sprite(0,0, 'background');

        // player
        player = game.add.sprite(0,0,'dude',5);

        game.physics.p2.enable(player);

        goal = game.add.sprite(615,280, 'treasure');

        game.physics.p2.enable(goal);

        goal.body.static = true;

        player.animations.add('left',[0,1,2,3],10,true);
        player.animations.add('right',[5,6,7,8],10,true);


        cursors = game.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();
    }


    function update()
    {
        if (go)
        {
            return;
        }

        player.body.velocity.x = 0;
        player.body.velocity.y = 0;

        if(cursors.left.isDown)
        {
          player.body.velocity.x = -150;
          player.animations.play('left');
        }
        else if(cursors.right.isDown)
        {
          player.body.velocity.x = 450;
          player.animations.play('right');
        }
        else if(cursors.up.isDown)
        {
          player.body.velocity.y = -150;
          player.animations.play('up');
        }
        else if(cursors.down.isDown)
        {
          player.body.velocity.y = 450;
          player.animations.play('down');
        }
        else {
          player.animations.stop();
          player.frame = 4;
        }

        // Checks for treasure and calls goal funcn
        this.game.physics.arcade.overlap(this.player, this.goal, this.collideHandler, null, this);


          game.collideHandler = function(player,goal)
          {
            goal.destroy();
            console.log("done");
            go = true;
          }
    }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Phaser 2 has a couple of different physics systems that can be used. In this case it looks like you're mixing two of them, Arcade and P2.

[Part 7 of the official Phaser 2 tutorial](https://phaser.io/tutorials/making-your-first-phaser-2-game/part7) has an example of having a character and a collectible, and an interaction when the two overlap.

In your case, you want `game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);` enabled instead of `game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.P2JS);`. You also want to enable arcade physics on the individual sprites, like `game.physics.arcade.enable(player);`.

I would highly recommend following, and tweaking, the official tutorial above first for a consistent learning experience; it's rather good.

Looking at your code, you also have another issue of note.

In your `update` you have this code:

```
game.collideHandler = function(player,goal)
{
    goal.destroy();
    console.log("done");
    go = true;
}
```

The `update` is actually run many times per second, at which point you're redefining `game.collideHandler`.

Instead, you should define the function outside of the `update` so it's defined only once. Again, part seven of the official tutorial showcases this as well. The creator of Phaser did a good job with it. :)

Comment: I have referenced and followed the very same tutorial, obviously cause it's on the actual phaser website. And no, I didn't mix 2 physics systems. As you can see, the Arcade is in comments, I left it there cause I don't know which one to use. And thanks for pointing out the collideHandler error, I changed it. I updated my question with the error I'm getting, if you can check it out.

Comment: The error you're getting is reinforcing what I'm seeing in your code. Your running code is only going to start P2: `game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.P2JS);`. However, you're then trying to use a system (arcade) that isn't started: `this.game.physics.arcade.overlap`. If you comment that line out you'll find that your game will start, but you won't be able to collect the treasure. See https://jsfiddle.net/strivinglife/81x50dLb/, where I've commented that line out.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/strivinglife/0vyutqdj/ is it switched to arcade completely. Done over lunch break, so some cleanup/optimizations could be made, but it expands upon the above. Note that switching to arcade does mean you have to do some extra work to get P2-like functionality, otherwise if you switch to P2 you may have to implement your own overlap. See https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser/issues/2804 for a starting point.